# How to execute programme on multiple linux machines

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

My machine has access to 15 other machines via the ssh protocol

```
ssh machine_1
```

each with 8 CPUs.

My executable is located in `root/bin/` and a series of input files are located in `root/input/`. I have approximately 20.000 input files and my goal is to simultaneously compute as many as possible to speed up the process.

Better said, I would like to run 6 (or 8) input files simultaneously on all 15 machines. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007176/5970596) but sadly, this will run the same command on all machines, which is not useful to me because I don't need to compute duplicate results.

My goal is to run 6 (to 8) different commands for a given machine, for example

```
# machine_1 would be running:
./bin/executable ../input/file_0 
./bin/executable ../input/file_1 
./bin/executable ../input/file_2 
./bin/executable ../input/file_3
# while machine_2 would at the same time work with
./bin/executable ../input/file_4
./bin/executable ../input/file_5 
./bin/executable ../input/file_6 
./bin/executable ../input/file_7
# and so on...
```

It get's more tricky. When execution (for example `./bin/executable ../input/file_0`) finishes, it should automatically move to next not-yet-computed file from the `root/input/`.

Does anybody have an idea what is the cleanest way to do that?

## Note

The input files are rather small, but a single execution can still take about 24 hours. So running 6 (or 8) such files on a single machine, should significantly increase the speed. Furthermore, employing all 15 machines, should work even better. I am not sure how the "master" machine would know which files have been processed, that is why I am here asking for advice, because I am quite sure I am not the only one with such problem.

Comment: Unless the files are in the hundreds of megabytes range, or more, there's really no need to run this in parallel on 15 different systems. Your 8-core CPU should be able to handle it quite nicely with a few threads.  And even if the files are large, distributing them or transferring them over the network will be the major bottleneck of your proposed design.

Comment: However, to help you with your problem, since the input files seems to be sequentially named, why not rework your program to take three arguments: File base name, starting index, and ending index. Then the program can use a simple `for` loop and do each file in sequence.

Comment: Also, even if you spread the load over multiple systems, I still recommend threads to further increase the parallelism.

Comment: Usually this is done using a load balancing scheduler, e.g. Slurm.

Comment: Furthermore, and to complicate things much more, how would the program know which files are done processing? That requires some kind of synchronization between all the programs running on all the different systems. And will add even further bottlenecks and complications. Keep things simple.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This kind of work scheduling is *extremely* common, and is beneficial across a wide range of tasks and input/output data sizes. Yes, fast IO is generally a prerequisite but there are storage vendors which specialise in this (Isilon being probably the most well known). There exist multiple entire industries to solve these issues, collectively valued at hundreds (thousands?) of billions of dollars.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The input files are rather small, but a single execution can still take about 24 hours. So running 6 (or 8) such files on a single machine, should significantly increase the speed. Furthermore, employing all 15 machined, should work even better. I am not sure how the "master" machine would know which files have been processed, that is why I am here asking for advice.

Comment: @skrat I would say that's pretty useful (if not crucial) information. Please include such information in the question itself. :)

Comment: This does not sound like a complicated task, given average knowledge+experience in network programming. Set `ClientAliveInteral` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to keep all the sockets sufficiently warm; `fork+exec ssh` to each machine, to run the executables, in parallel. Parent process `wait`s for each to terminate, and that's how the "master machine would know which files have been processed".